# What's the purpose of the "Capacity" selection in the "Format Volume" dialog?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, formatting

When formatting my hard drives or USB flash drives, I've always seen the "Capacity" cascade menu with only one option. The image below is taken when trying to format a 1 TB HDD on Windows 10.

[image]

If there's never been a second choice, why does this option exist in the first place?

This behavior is consistent across XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10 in more than ten years of my experience using a Windows OS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When formatting a floppy, I expect the same dialog to give a choice:

- 3.5'', 1.44MB, 512 bytes/sector
- 3.5'', 720KB, 512 bytes/sector

Currently I have no access to a floppy drive to confirm this, but on [this page](http://www.buildorbuy.org/floppydisk.html) there is a picture that shows a "Format A:\" window with these options. It comes from a time when "formatting" would actually initialize the physical structure of the medium – not just write some data for creating a filesystem.

[image]

Source: http://www.buildorbuy.org/images/floppywin2.png

It's possible other media (nowadays uncommon media) provide more than one option as well.

Comment: including the image here would be better, as the link may rot in the future

Comment: @phuclv I'm not sure if I can simply upload somebody else's file to imgur. The linked site has a copyright notice. Embedding their asset seems even worse. If you disagree then please improve the answer. It's community wiki now.

Comment: @phuclv In case the link rots, [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20181215174756/http://www.buildorbuy.org/floppydisk.html) is there to the rescue.

Comment: "initialize the physical structure of the medium " and "write some data for creating a filesystem" are the same thing as far as disk formatting is concerned

Comment: @OrangeDog [I seriously doubt it](https://superuser.com/q/1235480/432690).

Comment: Interestingly, when trying to reproduce this dialog in QEMU, both on XP and 7, I got only one capacity, 1.44M. So apparently, the floppy drive must support formatting to different capacity for this choice to exist.

Comment: "It's possible other media (nowadays uncommon media) provide more than one option as well." - The IBM AS/400 used to (and maybe still does) use 528 (or was it 520?) octet sectors. Therefore, all high-end IBM SCSI harddisks did support the `FORMAT UNIT` SCSI command, and you could re-format them from 512 to 520(528) and back. I would guess that this is still true for at least some high-end SAS disks. Also, I believe even today, tapes can still be formatted with different physical characteristics giving different tradeoffs between reliability and density.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I try to explain the difference between formatting, partitioning, and creating a filesystem [in my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1522286/2571). Please, let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 9):

The Windows "Format" dialog conflates three completely different concepts:

- *Formatting* a medium, which means create or change the *physical structure* of the medium, i.e. the width and number of tracks, the size of sectors or blocks, and so on. E.g. the same 3.5" floppy disk can be formatted in "Standard Density" (720 ko double-sided) or "High Density" (1.44 Mo double-sided), the difference is in how close together the tracks are spaced.
- *Partitioning* a medium, which means create or change some sort of "database" which separates the disk into multiple distinct areas. One of the simplest of those "databases" is the BIOS Partition Table Format, which is only 64 octets big and can only describe up to 4 partitions (although one or more of those partitions can be marked as "Extended Partitions", which means that they contain *another* Partition Table, which in turn can describe up to 4 partitions; by linking enough of those tables, you can describe an arbitrary number of partitions). A more complex format is the proprietary Windows Logical Disk Manager Format, whose internal structure actually *does* look like a database, it even has transactions and journaling to prevent data loss and corruption.
- *Creating a filesystem*, which means … well, exactly what it says.

The difference between the three is much more pronounced on other operating systems, e.g. Unix: *Formatting* is usually done with device-specific specialized tools for the specific hardware, e.g. `sg3_format` for disks implementing the SCSI Command Set, which sends a SCSI `FORMAT UNIT` command to the target. *Partitioning* is usually done with partitioning tools such as `fdisk`, `sfdisk`, `parted`, or `gparted`. *Creating a filesystem* is usually done with tools named `mkfs.<name of filesystem>`, e.g. `mkfs.ext3`, `mkfs.ntfs`, and so on.

Depending on the device, and the current state of the device, Windows' "Format" dialog will either create a filesystem or first partition the medium and then create a filesystem. In fact, one thing the "Format" dialog will almost never do, is actually "Format". The reason is simply that most modern devices *cannot* be formatted in-situ. The physical structure of a flash device is given by its internal organization. The physical structure of hard disks is so close to the edges of what is currently possible that the drive itself is not precise enough to write the tracks. The tracks can only be written by specialized hardware in the factory. The density is just too high, the tracks are too small and too close together to be written by the drive itself; it can only *find* where they are *if they are already there*, but it cannot write them.

So, considering that most devices cannot be formatted and thus the "Format" dialog cannot change their capacity, the dropdown may indeed look strange. But if a device *could* be formatted, then this dropdown would show the different possible capacities.

Note that a couple of years ago, when the changeover from 512 octet sectors to 4096 octet sectors happened, some drives did allow a limited form of "formatting", namely changing the sector size. However, this would typically not change the capacity, only the granularity of access.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your second bullet. I haven't ever heard that the *Format* dialog can do partitioning - I've always done this with `diskmgmt.msc`, `DiskPart.exe` or a 3rd-party tool or `fdisk` and `parted` on Linux (or just use LVM). Do you have sources to back this claim up?

Comment: +1 anyways. I didn't know about the difference between formatting and creating a filesystem (always thought `mke2fs` "formats" a volume to ext2/3/4).

Comment: It can't do _complex_ partitioning.  It can, however, create a single full-disk partition on a disk that has no partitions at all.

Comment: Coming from the un*,x world, I call creating a partition table "initializing", creating partitions "partitioning" and creating filesystems "formatting". When you talk about formatting, what I understand is "(re)creating a filesystem" and not physically changing tracks, sectors and sizes. For me, that's hardware configuration. The act or intention of deleting all files I call  "wiping the filesystem", not "formatting" as many other people do.

Comment: @xdevs23 so you are using the wrong terms!

Comment: @xdevs23 the distinction is between the creating-filesystems sort of "formatting" and "low-level formatting" that creates markers on the disk to tell its controller where the sectors are located.  The latter could be performed on floppy disks to create non-standard numbers of tracks and sectors. On hard drives, it generally requires software specifically written for the brand/model of drive, and is therefore written by the drive manufacturer, with an initial "sanity check" that queries the drive for its model number and aborts if it's not a compatible model.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great. In fact the "Capacity" field is equivalent to the `/F` option in the [`format` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format). The latest version only supports 1.44 but you can find older references around the internet:

> ```
> /F:size         The size of the floppy disk to format (720, 1.2, 1.44, 2.88, or 20.8).
> ```
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/format.html

Here's the [different `format` syntaxes for all DOS and Windows versions](https://www.computerhope.com/formathl.htm)

You can even specify the number of tracks per disk side and the number of sectors per track to format instead of using the `/F` option

> ```
> /T:tracks
>     Specifies the number of tracks on the disk. When possible, use the /F
>     switch instead of this switch. If you use the /T switch, you must also
>     use the /N switch. These two switches provide an alternative method of
>     specifying the size of the disk being formatted. You cannot use the /F
>     switch with the /T switch.
>
> /N:sectors
>     Specifies the number of sectors per track. When possible, use the /F
>     switch instead of this switch. If you use the /N switch, you must * also
>     use the /T switch. These two switches provide an alternative method of
>     specifying the size of the disk being formatted. You cannot use the /F
>     switch with the /N switch.
> ```
>
> https://www.infania.net/misc/dos622help/format.html

Comment: Good point for this discovery!